Exercise 3.39 in Function theory of one complex variables
${39.}$ Let $\varphi:D(0,1)\to D(0,1)$ be given by $\varphi(z)=z+a_2z^2+\ldots$. Define
$$\begin{align}
\varphi_{1}\left(z\right) &= \varphi\left(z\right), \\
\varphi_{2}\left(z\right) &=\varphi\circ\varphi\left(z\right),\\
\vdots &\quad \vdots \\
\varphi_j\left(z\right) &=\varphi\circ\varphi_{j-1}\left(z\right),
\end{align}$$
and so forth. Suppose that $\{\varphi_j\}$ converges uniformly on compact sets.
What can you say about $\varphi?$
I tried the Cauchy estimate and get that $|\varphi^{'}(0)\le||\varphi||_{\partial B(0,1)}\le1$, but that seems far from solving the problem.

Are you sure you wrote $\varphi$ correctly?  As is, the first line implies $\varphi(z)=z$ and we can ignore the sequence.

Yes yes, I now know the way to imply that $\varphi$ is exactly z with the help of my roommate. Thanks a lot!
